# Date Column showing Duplicate Records even after using to_date(to_char(JOB_CLOSED_DATE,'dd-mon-yy')),

Tags: sql, oracle, date, distinct

I have oracle query which should remove the duplicate records from a date column which consists of time as well. Because of time-stamp there are duplicate records are showing when include other columns along with the date columns. please see attached image from power bi. Is there any way I could be get rid of duplicacy of records.

```
Select distinct
to_date(to_char(JOB_CLOSED_DATE,'dd-mon-yy'))
From DWH_FACT_DISCRETE_JOB_WIP
```

[image]

Comment: Your code (above) does not match the image (date format). Please check and correct your post.

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and_ the expected result as formatted text, not as images.

Comment: why not just use `trunc(job_closed_date)`? That will truncate the date to the day, and won't require the use of format masks (why use `yy` for the year anyway? and why only specify one format mask?).

Comment: Is there any ID column in your database table ?

Comment: @FDavidov, The image is not from the Oracle, Its from Power BI. May be I am new to this forum so could not put up my question appropriately. Apologies for that.

Comment: @Boneist, the reason for not using Trunc is 'Trunc' will make the first date of the month but we want complete date.

Comment: @Ashish nope, `trunc(<date>)` is equivalent to `trunc(<date>, 'dd')` - i.e. it will truncate the start of the day. `trunc(<date>, 'mm')` would truncate to the start of the month. Try it for yourself: `select sysdate, trunc(sysdate), trunc(sysdate, 'dd'), trunc(sysdate, 'mm'), trunc(sysdate, 'hh') from dual;` N.B. you might need to change your NLS_DATE_FORMAT parameter to show the time part, if you're running that in something like SQL*Plus: `alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss;` See https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions236.htm#SQLRF06151

Comment: I am rephrasing the concern -  I have multiple date columns along with some more columns and one unique columns in my data set. The date columns have repetitive time stamp on this. The requirement is not to have duplicate records when I am using to_char(to_date(Date_Column),'dd-mon-yy')).

Comment: @Boneist, your suggestion seems appealing. I would be right back on this.

Comment: @Ashish are you saying if there are two date columns and two rows, and date_col1 has the same date for both, but date_col2 has different dates, you'd only want to see one value of the date_col1 in your query `select distinct date_col1, date_col2 from ...`?

Comment: @Boneist, This is my query- (In this I have total 9 date columns)
 
SELECT Distinct
JOB_ID,JOB_NUMBER,JOB_QUANTITY_COMPLETED,JOB_CLOSED_DATE,JOB_COMPLETED_DATE,JOB_CREATION_DATE,JOB_DUE_DATE,JOB_RELEASED_DATE,JOB_SCHD_COMPLETION_DATE,JOB_SCHD_START_DATE,JOB_LAST_UPDATE_DATE,COMP_DATE_REQUIRED From DWH_FACT_DISCRETE_JOB_WIP
Where to_char(JOB_CREATION_DATE,'YYYY')= to_char(SYSDATE,'YYYY')

Comment: Please edit your question to better reflect your scenario. Include what you currently get when you run the smallest version of your query that demonstrates the issue and what you want to see. Include sample data so that we can take your data and play with it ourselves. Bonus points to you if you can knock up a test case in [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18)

Answer (score 1):

First, implicit casting from char to date is very dangerous in oracle - it can result in hard to find bugs.

Second, try to use trunc() function instead of to_char() to get date without time.

```
Select distinct trunc(JOB_CLOSED_DATE)
From DWH_FACT_DISCRETE_JOB_WIP
```